# Cycle render views grey in viewport and (almost) wouldn't render

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, 3d-view

[the file itself here](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1dJX9xinO_-GF-5B7zYTv44U8obO9n93g?usp=sharing)

New learner here. I was trying to render an image/animation and the viewport on cycle mode wouldn't show anything, just all grey and outline of the selected objects. I read all the similar questions in the forum but seems nothing applies. I don't think it's simply the camera or object setting because:

1.If I leave the screen for a long time it would eventually show up again but would be gone if I move the screen.

2.I left it render before going to sleep and it appears rendered something in the morning.

3.Everything is fine with EEVEE mode, viewport, render, all fine.

so I think if the setting was wrong it just wouldn't render at all, if it helped with time given means it's too heavy or something complicated for the computer to run.

I will attach some screenshots, you can see in viewport is all grey and in render window is just empty. and sample 0 out of XXX. I will also attach one that appear it would eventually render something is you give eternity of time.

[image]
[image]

[image]

Comment: pls provide blend file

Comment: it was too big to load,,,, 155 mb

Comment: you can use google drive or any other cloud service...

Comment: link added! thanks!

Comment: also after all night to investigating, I found the problem was texture shading being too heavy, if I turn off the clouds(which where Volumetrics was applied) the render assumed normal. I also tried with different texture like Magic texture, it helps but still super super slow to render. I coudnt figure how to improve this, I have the new macbook pro, shouldnt be a machine that too weak to run

Comment: if you mean the m1 max...i don't think it is too weak to run...it depends on your scene/models etc.

Comment: as far as I dont have the object involved with Volumetrics texture or magic texture, it works all good, but I just cant work it out how to make the texture works, when it turns on, all night( 10 hrs) I just got 10% of 1 steal image done..... I'm at dead end :P